# Displaying authenticated user info on AppShell FlyoutHeaderTemplate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a flyout header that displays the authenticated user's avatar and name in the `FlyoutHeaderTemplate`.

The issue I ran into is that it looks like `OnAppearing()` method is not invoked at all for `AppShell`. I put break points in that method and never hit it.

I also tried using a `ContentView` to display the header in my Flyout but turns out `ContentView`'s don't have `OnAppearing()` or `OnDisappearing()` lifecycle events either.

How do I display authenticated user info in my flyout? I have the user info in my local database. All I need to do is:

1. Be able to call `var user = await _dbService.GetUser();` to read user info
2. I also need to be able to bind to certain controls i.e. `Label` for username and `Avatar` for user image.

Here's what I have in my `AppShell`:

```
<Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackLayout>
         <Label Text="{Binding ???}"/>
      </StackLayout>
   </DataTemplate>
</Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: It looks like shell has an [Appearing event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/lifecycle). Can you hook into that?

Comment: That's what I tried but it didn't fire. Actually when I read the info on the link you provided, it looks like the intended behavior for Appearing and Disappearing events for the Shell are a bit different. For example, that link says: "In a Shell application, pushing a modal page onto the modal navigation stack will result in all visible Shell objects raising the Disappearing event."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time you run the Appshell it will hit the constructor so you can call  `var user = await _dbService.GetUser();` in the constructor . Then Bind the shell to itself `this.BindingContext = this;`. Add a string property to bind it to the Text Label in xaml.

```
private string name;
public string Name { get{return name;} set { SetProperty(ref name, value); } 

public AppShell()
{
  InitializeComponent();
   Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        await GetUser();
                    });
  this.BindingContext = this;
}

public async void GetUser(){
  var user = await _dbService.GetUser();  
  Name = user.Name; 
}
```

The `OnAppearing()`  will hit whenever you go to  `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");`. So you can call `var user = await _dbService.GetUser();`   in it also.

Comment: Hello..... `SetProperty` is missing for AppShell. How can it be used?