# How to call SecureStorage.GetAsync from a bound property

Tags: maui

I have a flyout that will show the current logged in user.

When a user logs in, I call `SecureStorage` to store the user information, for example, `await SecureStorage.SetAsync("firstName", firstName);`

Now, I need to show that information in the Appshell flyout, so I created a property that is bound in the flyout XAML.

That property should call `await SecureStorage.GetAsync("email")`, for example,

```
public string UserEmail
{
    get { return await SecureStorage.GetAsync("email"); }
}
```

Of course, that does not work.

How is the best way to do this?

Comment: Quick question, do you understand INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Data binding and MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm) to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, which provides the ability for a class to raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever one of its properties changes.

I made a small sample for your reference.

Make sure your ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and then add `UserEmail` property like below:

```
private string _useremail; 

public string UserEmail
{
    get =>_useremail;
    set { 
         if(_useremail != value)
         {
             _useremail = value;
              OnPropertyChanged();
         }    
    }
}
```

Then set the `email` in your ViewModel or code-behind:

```
 SecureStorage.SetAsync("email","user@domain.com");
```

I use a Button to retrieve the `email` from secure storage:

```
async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string email = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("email");
      if (email != null) { 
          UserEmail = email;
      }
}
```

Comment: Hello... I implemented this and it really works when `SecureStorage` already has the data (because I load the SecureStorage data at view model constructor), however, if at some point the SecureStorage changes some value, the AppShell is not automatically updated. Your example makes use of a button click. I am trying to do the same overriding `OnAppearing` of `Shell` class, but that method is called once when app is first started. It is not called again. How can I do it?

Comment: I have injected the view model in the login dialog. When logged in, I call a method in the view model that sets the properties. It works, but the Shell does not show the new property value, even when the view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` :-(

Comment: I created the view model as a singleton, and in fact, the object properties are changed, but those changes are not reflected in the labels in the AppShell.

Comment: SecureStorage is used to store User's private and sensitive data such as their API keys. why don't you directly bind the label to `UserEmail`?

Comment: I am using SecureStorage  to store user information after he logins. When he logins, user information is retrieved from a cloud platform and stored locally so that user does not need to login again. I need to show that information in the flyout, but I was not able to do that.

Comment: You can refer to [Displaying authenticated user info on AppShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71504231/9644964) for an alternative solution.

Comment: I tried it, but I noticed the binding occurs before the `AppShell` constructor so when the binding is taking place, the values are empty.

Comment: I don't think call `public string UserEmail
{ get { return await SecureStorage.GetAsync("email"); }}` is possible. How about using [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?tabs=android) to store user infromation?